# How to save url into django model

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, url

I have a model called `Photo` and looks like this...

```py
class Photo(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    photo = models.FileField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    strength = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    combinations = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    favors = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    iscarousel = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s" % (self.created_at, self.photo, self.title, 
        self.kind, self.size, self.strength, self.combinations, self.favors, self.availability, 
        self.iscarousel)
```

I am can save to my aws s3 bucket but I do not have a url path to it, or so I believe this is the case. How can I save my model where once I upload my photo the url gets saved in my model as well. So I am thinking that I will need a url field and I know there is a models.UrlField or something like that. I am just curious though how I tell django to extract that url and add it to some field so I can later access it. If I don't have it I don't know how I am suppose to retrieve it to later show it on my web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you use ImageField instead of FileField you will get more related to images.  However both have a url attribute you can access from a django template or when querying for a specific image.

In your model it would look something like this:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
```

In a Django Template you would access it like this:

```
<img src="{{ img_obj.image.url}}" alt="connect" style="max-height:300px">
```

[Here is a reference](https://djangocentral.com/uploading-images-with-django/) to more info on how to set that up